# best practice: storing django models (db) in repository

Tags: django, git, django-south

I have some django models which are take quite long to create and I would like to know what is the best way of storing them in a repository such as git.

- One way would be just to serialize them and then have a function which stores them in the local db file
- Or just committing the db file in the repository.
- Or use the dumpdata django command

What is a common approach for solving this?

Comment: caching binary data in version control always comes with issues, many of them can be attributed to the fact that diff and merge do not work. on top of that, git sucks for big files.

Comment: are django models binary files?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can store the binary db file(no matter dumped from db or serialized by your app) in the local file server(ftp, file path, etc..).

Meanwhile commit **a resource file** which includes the path and some valid information about the right binary so that your app can find it and **a script file** used to restore it.